# 200 OK response even if redirection should be performed Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httpresponse

I am trying to redirect my web application when a page is requested but the session has not already been set. I use Express.js for the server side.

Here you are the code of the route on the server:

```
app.post("/api/auth/signin", async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  console.log(`Request JSON: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

  const userRequested = await db
    .collection("users")
    .findOne({ username: username });

  if (userRequested == null) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: "Requested user does not exist",
    });
    res.json(username);
  } else if (username == null || password == null) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: "Null username or password are not allowed",
    });
  } else {
    if (userRequested.password === password) {
      req.session.user = userRequested;
      res.status(200);
      res.json(userRequested);
      //redirect("/api/budget/whoami");
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({
        message: "Wrong credentials",
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Also, I use the following function:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session || !req.session.user){
  res.statusCode = 300;
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/index.html');
  }   else {
   next();
  }
});
```

The client performs the fetch in the following way:

```
async beforeMount() {
    console.log("Executing on page loading");

    await fetch("/api/budget/whoami", {
      method: "GET",
      redirect: "follow"
    })
      .then((res) => {

        if(res.status == 300){
          window.location.replace("index.html");
        }

          console.log("All good, getting the response");
          return res.json();
      })
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("Updating value");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        console.log(user.username);

        this.username = user.username;
        this.password = user.password;
        this.firstName = user.firstName;
        this.lastName = user.lastName;
      });
  }
```

Even if the login is not performed, I can see that the response status is 200 OK using Postman. Checking the response body, it is the HTML code of the login page where I want to redirect the user.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your patience.

Edit: I also post the response captured by Postman

[image: Postman Capture]

Comment: Is the route for `/api/budget/whoami` placed after your `app.use()`

Comment: @Keith yes it is

Comment: I would say it's a correct behavior .. because the 200 is the status of the after-redirect request... and you can see it successfully loaded ....  try to disable "Automatically follow redirects" in the Postman to get the 300 ... you should get then the 300 instead

Comment: moreover, you shouldn't be using 300 (that's not correct) ... either use 301 or 302.... ultimately, I don't think you should be using this HTTP redirect ... if we are talking about SPA (React, Vue, ..) just use the router to navigate to the login screen  ... no need to use that http response for redirecting